# How to execute two DELETE queries one after another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following queries

1. DELETE FROM A WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM B)
2. DELETE FROM B

I want to make sure that the first statement is complete before the second is executed since the 1) is dependent on 2)

I want to know if I execute these queries just like this, does SQL take care of completing the first transaction before starting the second? 
Or is there a way I can make sure that the second transaction starts only after the first is complete?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute queries in succession by separating them with a semicolon `;`. More details are in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html).

Simply do:

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM B); DELETE FROM B;
```

Based on your requirement; this does exactly what you asked for based on the below example:

```
mysql> select sleep(5); show databases;
+----------+
| sleep(5) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (5.00 sec)

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
|         ...        |
+--------------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

You can do this with `mysql -e` command and virtually any mysql library (such as the one with php).

Comment: a semi-colon is a statement terminator. It does not 'chain' commands togther.

Comment: Not all client interfaces support multi-query like this.

Answer (score 1):

If the statements are in the same batch it's guaranteed.

But you might want to wrap them in a transaction to ensure that either both happen or neither happen (get rolled back).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, MySQL executes only one statement at a time in a given session. So there's no way the second statement could start before the first is finished (assuming you execute them in the same thread).

I'll offer another alternative:
How about using a multi-table DELETE from both tables in one statement?

```
DELETE A, B FROM A RIGHT OUTER JOIN B USING (id);
```

The type of join I use above means that *all* rows from B will be deleted, and also rows in A which have matching id values, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the delete statements inside a transaction / try catch block.  If one delete statement encounters an error, you can "roll back" the state of your database to before the transaction started.  Here's an example.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    --Your sequence of SQL statements here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```